# Laravel 5.7 Login Error: These credentials don't match our records

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm very new to Laravel 5.7. I'm working on an assignment that requires a user to login in order to do CRUD functions. My CRUD is working fine, but I am having a problem with the login system.

I'm using the default login from laravel (auth), and I can register and it logs me in. However, my problem is when I log out, I am unable to login again. The email field becomes red and it tells me

" These credentials do not match our records."

But it is exactly as it is in the database. I am using the default login and have not changed anything except for adding a logout function in the LoginController.

I have tried searching google and here but have not found any answers. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Edit:
These are my codes:

routes

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('aboutinfo');

Route::get('/logout', 'YourController@logout');
```

LoginController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Auth;
use Redirect;
use Session;
use Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected function authenticated() {
    if (Auth::check()) {
        return redirect()->route('aboutinfo');
    }
}

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function logout(Request $request)  {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        $request->session()->invalidate();

        return redirect('/');
 }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends('allayout')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Login') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="remember">
                                        {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                    {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('aboutinfo');
    }
}
```

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->user_password;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getKey()
    {
        return $this->user_id;
    }

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
}
```

Is there anything that I've done wrong?

Comment: show your code please so that we can understand what is the problem

Comment: Are you definitely using the same password you used when registering the user (and not the value stored in the database)?

Comment: Have you changed the name of the password field in your database??

Comment: Yes, I am using the same password when registering and I have changed the password field.

Answer (score 0):

So, after researching for a few hours, I've found out that it didn't work because of the `'user_id'`, because in my database it was `id` . That solved my problem!